# Where to put hiera files in puppet hiera setup

Tags: puppet, hiera

I have a running puppet master-agent setup and currently trying to figure out how to use hiera to provision php.

My Puppetfile:

```
forge "http://forge.puppetlabs.com"

mod "jfryman/nginx"
mod "puppetlabs/mysql"
mod "mayflower/php"
mod 'puppetlabs-vcsrepo'
mod 'puppetlabs/ntp', '4.1.0'
mod 'puppetlabs/stdlib'
```

My `site.pp`:

```
hiera_include('classes')
```

My `environment.conf`, where the modulepath is maintained:

```
manifest = site.pp
modulepath = modules:site
```

My hiera config on puppet master at `/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/hiera.yml`:

```
---
:backends:
  - yaml
:hierarchy:
  - "nodes/%{::trusted.certname}"
  - "environment/%{server_facts.environment}"
  - common

:yaml:
# datadir is empty here, so hiera uses its defaults:
# - /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/%{environment}/hieradata on *nix
# - %CommonAppData%\PuppetLabs\code\environments\%{environment}\hieradata on Windows
# When specifying a datadir, make sure the directory exists.
  :datadir:
```

From what I understand, general config that should be present on all servers goes into `common.yaml`. With this setup, I managed to install ntp on my node with this config at `hieradata/common.yaml`:

```
---
classes:
 - 'profile::base'

ntp::servers:
  - server 0.de.pool.ntp.org
  - server 1.de.pool.ntp.org
  - server 2.de.pool.ntp.org
  - server 3.de.pool.ntp.org
```

Now, my hierarchy also states that all node specific config should go into `hieradata/nodes/{fqdn-of-the-node}.yml`.

Now, finally coming to my questions:

I have a file `hieradata/nodes/myserver.example.com.yml` which holds this:

```
classes:
  - 'profile::php'
```

And a manifest under `site/profile/manifests/php.pp`:

```
class profile::php {
  class { '::php': }
}
```

But this does not provision php. As you saw, I use `mayflower/php` from the forge.

Now, my two questions are:

Is my hiera file for php in the right location? What am I missing then to make it provision php to my agent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have multiple issues/possibilities here, so let us go through them iteratively.

---

First, you are using the default `datadir` of:

```
/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/%{environment}/hieradata
```

However, you have a priority of:

```
"environment/%{server_facts.environment}"
```

This does not make sense, since you have a priority that distinguishes data for nodes based on their directory environment, but you also are placing hieradata directly in directory environments. If you want priority based on directory environment, then change your hieradata directory to be outside the direct environments at:

```
/etc/puppetlabs/code/hieradata
```

Otherwise, you should remove that level from your priority as it adds no value and will increase lookup times.

---

Second, you did not show your `site.pp`, but did you remember your `hiera_include('classes')`? That will lookup the array `classes` and then include them, which is what it seems you want. If you are not doing it, then the node provisioning issue you described would occur.

---

Third, is `site` in your `modulepath`? You need to append it in either your `puppet.conf` or your `environment.conf`.

---

Fourth, your node's `fqdn` may not match the `certname`. Check the certs directory on your Puppetmaster for the node's cert.

---

Side notes:

- The first half of your question contains a lot of extraneous information and is missing a lot of helpful relevant information. Please consider editing the question to provide more helpful information and to be more concise.
- Since `ntp` worked, I am assuming your module install with `r10k` into the environment directories succeeded. Also I am assuming that the modules are present for the directory environment of your node.
- There is no real reason to specify the `php` class as global in your declaration with `::php`.

Comment: Thanks! I shortened the intro. Also, I added my site.pp and my environment.conf which holds the modulepath. Moreover, I check my certs with `puppet cert list --all` and the certname is included in there and has the `+` which I understand means it was added. Moreover, I removed the environment-part from the hierarchy as you suggested. I did not really plan to use it anyway. Still, it does not provision php.

Comment: Actually, I don't know what you mean with having php as a global module. The modules are present in my environment path.

Comment: @Chrisissorry I updated the answer to clarify the global `php` declaration comment.